# Different color of one unicode symbol

Tags: html, css

I use the unicode symbol ⏬ on my webpage. The problem is that this symbol is displayed good in chrome of the linux but in chrome of the windows 10 this symbol has the border and blue background color.

Here is my code: `<div>Hello world &#9196;</div>`

Could anybody help me please?

Comment: Please, read '[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)' and update your question.

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: Sorry, I've just added it: <div>Hello world &#9196;</div>

Answer (score 1):

Well this is something which are rendered by the browser dom itself. Every engines are showing something else, instead those who has the same engine. There are some possible ways to change the style a bit by changing the font-family where it's writing in.

If you want, you could do it by HTML and CSS by making a background image or do it with simply using font-awesome!

Hopefully this is a answer on your question.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div>Hello world &#9196;</div>
```

Since you haven't set any font, the browser will use whatever default font it has. In Chrome, that means colour fonts:

[image: Chrome]

As with any other piece of text, if you need to have full control on how it looks you need to set your own font. For instance, Google provides the [Noto](https://www.google.com/get/noto/) family, which includes two emoji fonts (monochrome and colour).

An alternative is to handle it as icon and use either SVG or an iconic font.

Comment: @EgorTitov "Tried some fonts" is pretty vague. Do you mean that you've used CSS to embed an emoji font that contains the ⏬ character?

Comment: Álvaro González, I mean that I have used some fonts like Arial, Times New Roman. Thank you I will try to use an emoji font